# Numerals with ь at the end

Tags: перевод, грамматика, числительные

Which numerals have a ь at the end and which have in the middle?

Comment: Was it your homework?

Comment: No. It was not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me jump in with some extracurricular findings.

In speech, some people would palatalize the sound /т/ and you'll have a /т'/ gravitating towards /ц/ at the end of these numerals:

> `50 - пятьдесят 
>   60 - шестьдесят 
>   70 - семьдесят 
>   80 - восемьдесят 
>   500 - пятьсот 
>   600 - шестьсот 
>   и т.д.`

This phenomenon doesn't affect the spelling, but you'd hear the palatalization, which may be confusing. Keeping this in mind may be of use when working on a transcript. Say, /пятьдесять/ pops up in someone's speech, and you're in two minds about how to spell it.

Also, according to [this source](https://books.google.se/books?id=6nJgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22&source=bl&ots=fWwFzGsAUx&sig=F0-Wu07IRXwxy0kwDjqOjB7m-nc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixubOv-NvKAhXEqXIKHbtiD9Q4ChDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C%22&f=false), they used to spell these numerals with "ь" at the end in the 17th century.

Answer (score 2):

Many have an "**ь**" in the end:

```
5 - пять  
6 - шесть 
7 - семь 
20 - двадцать
30 - тридцать
и т.д.
```

And many have a "**ь**" in the middle:

```
50 - пятьдесят
60 - шестьдесят
70 - семьдесят
80 - восемьдесят
500 - пятьсот
600 - шестьсот
и т.д.
```

Answer (score 0):

Which numerals have a 'ь' at the end?

```
5 - пять
6 - шесть
7 - семь
8 - восемь
9 - девять
10 - десять
11 - одиннадцать
12 - двенадцать
13 - тринадцать
14 - четырнадцать
15 - пятнадцать
16 - шестнадцать
17 - семнадцать
18 - восемнадцать
19 - девятнадцать
20 - двадцать
30 - тридцать
```

Which numerals have a 'ь' in the middle?

```
50 - пятьдесят
60 - шестьдесят
70 - семьдесят
80 - восемьдесят
500 - пятьсот
600 - шестьсот
700 - семьсот
800 - восемьсот
```

About pronunciation:

Numbers 11-30 (which I have written) ends with т' if pronounced slowly and т' with approach to ц' in fluent speech.